# Is it allowed for the quarterback (or someone else) to punt the ball if he can't find another play?

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl

If the quarterback (or someone else) on fourth down gets in trouble and hasn't passed the line of scrimmage, can he change the intended play and instead punt the ball away?